# apache kafka throwing an exception for scala

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to compile and run a simple `kafka` code that is a sample from `Aapche`.When compiling I am getting the following exception, even after adding all the `lib` files for `scala` (i guess).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at scala.Predef$.Integer2int(Predef.scala:303)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$$anonfun$parseBrokerList$1.apply(ClientUtils.scala:103)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$$anonfun$parseBrokerList$1.apply(ClientUtils.scala:102)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:44)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.map(ArrayBuffer.scala:44)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.parseBrokerList(ClientUtils.scala:102)
at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.<init>(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:32)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.<init>(DefaultEventHandler.scala:41)
at kafka.producer.Producer.<init>(Producer.scala:60)
at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.<init>(Producer.scala:26)
at kafkaTest.TestProducer.main(TestProducer.java:23)
```

This is my `program`:

```
package kafkaTest;

import java.util.*;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class TestProducer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // long events = Long.parseLong(args[0]);

    long events = 10l;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "broker1:9092,broker2:9092 ");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    ***![props.put("partitioner.class", "kafkaTest.SimplePartitioner");][1]***//this is line no 23
    props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
    Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

      for (long nEvents = 0; nEvents < events; nEvents++) { long runtime =
      new Date().getTime(); String ip = "192.168.2.1" + rnd.nextInt(255);
      String msg = runtime + ",www.example.com," + ip; KeyedMessage<String,
      String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("page_visits", ip,
      msg); producer.send(data); }

    producer.close();
}
}
```

The attached is the screen shot of library files.
Please let me know the cause of `error/exception`.

Edit: this is `SimplePartitioner.java`

```
package kafkaTest;

import kafka.producer.Partitioner;
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties;

public class SimplePartitioner implements Partitioner {
public SimplePartitioner(VerifiableProperties props) {
}

public int partition(Object key, int a_numPartitions) {
    int partition = 0;
    String stringKey = (String) key;
    int offset = stringKey.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (offset > 0) {
        partition = Integer.parseInt(stringKey.substring(offset + 1))
                % a_numPartitions;
    }
    return partition;
}
}
```

Comment: can you attach your `SimplePartitioner` implementation as well? Without the partitioner part works fine for me

Comment: it worked for you??? Can u mention the steps again for compiling a running, and the jars that u have used.

Comment: The code with partitioner works fine as well for me

Comment: I used gradle for `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.1` and `org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4` dependencies. And your code sure. Everything worked as expected

Comment: Ok,so there is no issue with the code. I am trying one more example that just pushes up the dates. That code is unable to fetch the metadata and fails after 3 tries and I am not understanding the broker part of the code.from `metadata.broker.list` property, I am basically saying producer to look at that address. But I have not specified that address anywhere. So this is the way or I am getting it completely wrong.

Comment: `metadata.broker.list` is used for broker discovery and not necessarily all brokers should be listed there. Each broker registers itself in Zookeeper and knows about all other brokers in cluster and is able to get their addresses from Zookeeper. So you may actually pass just one broker to `metadata.broker.list` and producer should work fine as long as that broker is alive.

Comment: I am using the sandbox VM of horton works, so its preconfigured and I dont know how to list up all the brokers and/or their ports. If there is any way to get that, tit would be nice .

Answer (score 1):

There's a space at the end of your broker list :

`props.put("metadata.broker.list", "broker1:9092,broker2:9092 ");`

Remove it and it should work fine then :

`props.put("metadata.broker.list", "broker1:9092,broker2:9092");`

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when `metadata.broker.list` has a broker with no port number.